# UWP Error 0x8007007B: Opening the package failed

Tags: uwp

I have a sideloading UWP app that I digitally signed with signtool. I have distributed it to several computers without a problem. On one particular computer, however, I get the above-mentioned error message.

I have followed the troubleshooting guide [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/how-to-troubleshoot-app-package-signature-errors]

The computer recognizes the certificate used for signing, it is in the 'TrustedPeople' category and accepted as 'Ok'. So, I think there is no problem with the certificate. I have noticed, however, that when I examine the properties of the .msixbundle-file, on the computer where I have the problem the 'Digital Signatures' tab is missing. Any suggestions on what is going wrong here?

Many thanks!

Comment: Based on your post, you have successfully installed your app on many devices. So the issue should not be related to your package and certificate.  I'd suggest you check the OS version of these devices first. And try to create a simple blank APP to test again on that specific device.

Comment: Thank you, Roy. Do you have any explanation for why the 'Digital Signatures' tab is missing from the properties? To me, it seems that the certificate information which should be an integral part of the installer file has been lost. How can that happen?

Comment: Is the package the same package that you installed on other devices? If it is, then I still think the issue should be related to the device not the package.

Comment: Yes, it is the same package and, yes, I also think that it is due to the device, not the package. It seems to be an official copy of Win 10. Any suggestion of what is wrong on the device?

Comment: Have you checked the OS version for these devices? And is there some special group policies for that device？